# java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree: throws NoSuchFileException on a root directory of an empty NTFS volume

Tags: java, file, directory, ntfs

Consider this Java method:

```
private void printContents(final Path start) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Finding the contents of " + start);

    Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            System.out.println("preVisitDirectory: " + dir);    // do this to indicate progress
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            System.out.println("visitFile: file = " + file);    // do this to indicate progress
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }

        @Override public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException ioe) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("visitFileFailed: file = " + file + ", ioe = " + ioe);   // do this to indicate progress
            throw ioe;
        }
    } );
}
```

It usually works fine, printing out the directory contents, with almost any value for start that you give it.

But suppose that the start arg is actually the root directory of an NTFS volume (e.g. a drive letter like "G:") and suppose that the volume is empty (i.e. has no contents).  Then printContents throws a NoSuchFileException with this stack trace:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: G:
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsDirectoryStream.<init>(WindowsDirectoryStream.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:518)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:457)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:300)
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:322)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2662)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)
    at FileTreeComparer.printContents(FileTreeComparer.java:457)
    ...
```

Why does this happen, and is there any work around?

I note that if the start arg is the root directory of an empty FAT32 volume, this causes no problem.

Furthermore, if the start arg is some subdirectory of the root directory on an NTFS volume (e.g. G:\tmp) then that also causes no problem, regardless of whether or not it is empty.

No, the problem seems to be isolated to NTFS root directories that are empty.

Comment: Have you tried passing "G:\" instead of "G:"?

Comment: @Andrea: I should have mentioned in my original posting that I tried G:\ and G:/ as well as just G: but it does not matter: all 3 variants fail exactly the same way.